# Restaurar configuracion NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Como puedo restaurar la configuracion de netBeans? estuve tocando muchas cosas para ver si podía crear al fin un ejecutable .JAR (Cosa que no pude) y de tanto tocar se me cambiaron algunas cosas, como por ejemplo los colores. Fui a fonts and color y le di a restore y sigue igual. Como ven en la imagen los colores se ven espantosos, esos no son los que tenía antes. Hay alguna forma de restaurarlo?

Probé desinstalar e instalar netBeans, pero por algún motivo no de me desinstala del todo, ya que al instalarlo de vuelta, vuelvo a tener mi configuracion por defecto, como mis plugins y color de fondo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]